# Can we use a row of data frame as input of a function?

Tags: r

I am doing a simulation study and I have built a data frame with specified input of a function.
Can I use a row of data frame as the input of the function? See the for loop below.

```
alpha<-0.05
beta<-0.1
par<-expand.grid(
  d_s=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
  m=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
  c=c(4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20),
  rho=c(0,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.07,0.09, 0.1, 0.15,0.2),
  Lambda=c(0.25,0.5,1,2,4)
)
par$n0<-c()
for(k in 1:dim(par)[1]){
   par$n0[k]<-get.n0(alpha=alpha,beta = beta,
                     rho = par[k,"rho"],m=par[k,"m"],c=par[k,"c"],d_s = par[k,"d_s"],Lambda = par[k,"Lambda"])
 } #not productive
```

I attached get.n0 but it's not important for my question. You can look at it if you want.

```
get.n0<-function(one.sided=T,alpha ,beta, d_s, m, c, rho, Lambda=1/(1-rho)){

  z1<-ifelse(one.sided,qnorm(1-alpha),qnorm(1-alpha/2)) #if one sided test z1 =z(1-alpha), if two sided z1=z(1-alpha/2) 
  #print(z1)
  z2<-qnorm(1-beta)
  #print(z2)
  n1<-m*c
  n0 <- 1/((d_s/(z1+z2))^2-((Lambda+(m-1)*Lambda*rho)/n1))
  if(n0 < 0){
    return(0)
  }else{
    return(ceiling(n0))
  }
}
```

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you. I just updated the code . Do you mean ```apply(par, 2, get.n0)``` ?I tried this but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you? I mean.. Yes, you can, indeed you did already. But I'd suggest you to do it with `pmap` from the `purrr` package.

Look at this:

```
get.n0<-function(one.sided = TRUE, alpha, beta, d_s, m, c, rho, Lambda = 1/(1-rho)){

  z1 <- ifelse(one.sided,qnorm(1-alpha),qnorm(1-alpha/2)) #if one sided test z1 =z(1-alpha), if two sided z1=z(1-alpha/2) 
  #print(z1)
  z2 <- qnorm(1-beta)
  #print(z2)
  n1 <- m*c
  n0 <- 1/((d_s/(z1+z2))^2-((Lambda+(m-1)*Lambda*rho)/n1))

  if(n0 < 0){
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(ceiling(n0))
  }
}

alpha <- 0.05
beta  <- 0.1
par <- expand.grid(

  d_s    = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
  m      = c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
  c      = c(4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20),
  rho    = c(0,0.01,0.03,0.05,0.07,0.09, 0.1, 0.15,0.2),
  Lambda = c(0.25,0.5,1,2,4)

)

par$n0 <- purrr::pmap_dbl(par, get.n0, alpha = alpha, beta = beta)
```

`pmap_dbl` always returns a double vector.

`pmap` takes a dataframe and takes one row a time. Since the columns of `par` are equal to the arguments of the function, this works just perfectly.

Technically, `pmap` doesn't take one row a time, but rather takes the i-th element of each column at each i-run, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` row-wise with `MARGIN = 1` and pass the respective inputs from the column to the function.

```
output <- apply(par, 1, function(x) {
         get.n0(TRUE, alpha, beta, as.numeric(x["d_s"]), as.numeric(x["m"]), 
                      as.numeric(x["c"]), as.numeric(x["rho"]), 0)
         })

head(output, 10)
# [1] 857 215  96  54  35 857 215  96  54  35
```